# World_Eckert_IV to Latitude/Longitude projection is incorrect

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, pyproj

I'm using pyproj to transform between coordinate systems. 
Here is my .prj file:

```
PROJCS["World_Eckert_IV",
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Eckert_IV"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],
UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

where I call

```
project = partial(pyproj.transform,
                  pyproj.Proj(proj="eck4"),
                  pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'))

output["Latitude"] =\
    dataframe['geometry'].apply(lambda x: transform(project, x)).y
output["Longitude"] =\
    dataframe['geometry'].apply(lambda x: transform(project, x)).x
```

However, the latitude/longitude coordinates that I get back do not point to where they should. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide example input and expected output?

Comment: Yes, an example from World Eckert IV is (3783390.530, -215436.014). My output should be somewhere in Kenya.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me - the lat,lon are in Kenya:

```py
>>> from pyproj import Transformer
>>> wkt = '''PROJCS["World_Eckert_IV",
... GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
... DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
... SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
... PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
... UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
... PROJECTION["Eckert_IV"],
... PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
... PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
... PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],
... UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'''
>>> transformer = Transformer.from_crs(wkt, "epsg:4326", always_xy=True)
>>> lon, lat = transformer.transform(3783390.530, -215436.014)
>>> lon, lat
(40.25250000355127, -1.6344440031753034)
```

I would recommend doing something like:

```py
lon, lat = transformer.transform(dataframe.geometry.x, dataframe.geometry.y)
output["Latitude"] = lat
output["Longitude"] = lon
```